# Laravel Event Listener

Tags: php, laravel

I created an Event/Dispatch Stack with the help of Laracast. The event service provider class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Log\Writer;

class EventingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
        $listeners =  $this->app['config']->get('medifaktor.listeners');

        foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
            $this->app['events']->listen('medifaktor.*', $listener);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example for a Listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\Responder;

use App\Events\EventListener;
use App\Events\Responder\ResponderWasRegistered;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use App\Events\Responder\ResponderStatusWasUpdated;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

// Responder was registered
class ResponderRegistered extends EventListener {

    // Variables
    use DispatchesJobs;

    public function whenResponderWasRegistered(ResponderWasRegistered $event) {

    }
}
```

The output of the listeners array:

```
array (
  0 => 'App\\Listeners\\Dispatch\\DispatchCreated',
  1 => 'App\\Listeners\\Incident\\IncidentCreated',
  2 => 'App\\Listeners\\MFUser\\MFUserRegistered',
  3 => 'App\\Listeners\\Responder\\ResponderDispatched',
  4 => 'App\\Listeners\\Responder\\ResponderStatusUpdated',
  5 => 'App\\Listeners\\Responder\\ResponderLocationUpdated',
  6 => 'App\\Listeners\\Responder\\ResponderRegistered',
)  



  $registerResponderCommand = new RegisterResponderCommand($bodyContent);
    $this->commandBus->execute($registerResponderCommand);
```

I am using Laravel 5.5 now and as it seems `$this->app['events']->listen` is not being recognized anymore. How do you adjust this correctly? According to a debug message in the IDE, this method is not found. Has this been outdated?

Comment: What error are you getting when you run the code? Not in the IDE

Comment: Actually the code is not executed. I tested it by logging the execution of the method, but nothing is happening when I log within the foreach. Outside it is working fine.

Comment: If the foreach doesn't get executed it means the $listeners array is empty

Comment: I checked that as well. The listeners are loaded. But the command ->listen does not get executed.

Comment: Please be more specific. If $listeners is not empty and the foreach is executed, then the listen method gets executed as well, unless you're getting an error. So,are you saying that listeners don't get executed when event is broadcasted?

Comment: Exactly. I added an example listener. Anything inside the whenResponder.. function does not get executed

Comment: Could you dump the $listeners array? And the piece of code that broadcasts the event?

Comment: The code you posted dispatches a command, it doesn't broadcast an event, that's the first thing. Secondly, elements in the $listeners array should define a method that should be called on event OR the listener class should define a handle() method. - see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-listeners